# restriction of datas in ms sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Am running a web application using asp.net,c# and sql sever 2005.Am having the condition that if if enter the button with blank fields,those blank datas should not entered into the database,but it is getting inserted for me in database.how should i avoid that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a [CHECK constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx)

```
ALTER TABLE Mytable WITH CHECK ADD
    CONSTRAINT CK_Mytable_MyColumn CHECK (MyColumn <> '')
```

You'll need to clean up data first with an UPDATE + prepare your code to deal with the SQLExceptions that wil happen when you do try to insert an empty string

This idea can be extended to NULL too with the NOT NULL constraint

Comment: Wont work. Then you get a SQL error. Sounds more like the poster needs to add some logic to his form and not even try an inswert.

Comment: @TomTom: correct. CHECK constraint should never fire but it protects data integrity.

Comment: Agree on that. Still this issue must be handled earlier with proper input vlaidation and nice feedback to the user if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Am having the condition that if if
>   enter the button with blank
>   fields,those blank datas should not
>   entered into the database

You mean, when no fiels are entered, you dont enter?

> how should i avoid that?

It is called programming. Basiaclly not a SQL issue to start with. Your form should check whether or not it should make an insert or not. If not it should not even touch sql server.